# ssh login and kill process

Tags: ssh, kill

I want to ssh on a remote machine and kill all java process on that machine.
I have authorized this machine to ssh on without password so I use command:

```
ssh remote "kill -9 `pgrep java`"
```

but I got:

```
bash: line 0:kill (23779) -No such process
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Running

```
ssh remote "kill -9 `pgrep java`"
```

will run the subprocess `pgrep java` on **your** machine, not the remote one. If you want to run it on the remote machine, you need to enclose the arguments with apostrophes instead of double quotes:

```
ssh remote 'kill -9 `pgrep java`'
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using

```
ssh remote "kill $(pidof java)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `kill` with `pkill`:

```
ssh remote "pkill java"
```

Comment: This is a workaround using different commands. The original problem is not resolved. See my answer.